# jQuery, behaviour changing when I call the jQuery function outerHeight()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the elevateZoom plugin of jQuery.

By default, the lens does not closes when the mouse pointer reaches the corner: http://jsfiddle.net/qozp328p/

But if I add a mouseover event, where I call `outerWidth()`, then, the lens closes when the mouse reaches the corner of the image: http://jsfiddle.net/z48fs7vL/

How can it be? how can calling this function, changing a script behaviour?

(I am using Firefox 31.1.0)
thanks.

Comment: I tried the 2 samples in Chrome, I didn't see a different behavior.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasAlbert - at least now I know it is not a jQuery feature

Comment: Does also work in IE 11, but can confirm the described behavior for FF 30.0 / Win7